# Finding multiple patterns in a string in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I am trying to find strings in an array that match multiple regular expression patterns. I figured out how to do this for one pattern as below:

```
spamWords = Regexp.new("Delighted")

spamCount1 = 0
spamArray.each do |word|
  if word =~ spamWords
    spamCount1 +=1
  end
end
p spamCount1
```

I iterated over an array of `spamWord` strings, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: If you just want to count rather than get the matches, then you should do: `smapArray.count(&spamWords.method(:=~))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union multiple patterns into one regular expression, then perform the search exactly like you did below:

```
spamWords = Regexp.new("Delighted|Saddened")
```

You can also use `Regexp.union` to auto-generate this regexp for you:

```
spamWords = Regexp.union("Delighted", "Saddened")
```